# Can't create facebook account in Gwibber

Tags: gwibber, facebook

Can't create a facebook account.
I start the procedure, add account, insert mail and password then it writes me back on a white page "success" and stops.

The account isn't create (seeing on youtube there are two or three more steps to do) but gwibber don't let me go ahead; i can only press close.

I tried to do this, remove all the gwibber references on my home

```
~/.config/gwibber
~/.cache/gwibber
```

and reboot. Nothing.

Then i tried to uninstall it via UBC and install it back. Nothing.

Any ideas??